# json values to string array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new in this community and I just started programming.
I couldn't find anything about this topic, so i decided to start a new... if it's wrong  please let me know.

Well, I've the following problem... i want to put the values of an JSON-Object into a string array in Javascript.

What I've got looks like this:

```
{"prop1":"hello","prop2":"world!"}
```

what i need should look like this

```
stringarray = [hello, world];
```

How can I get the values (hello & world) of the JSON object and put them into a string array without these special characters (", :) and without the properties (prop1, prop2)?

Comment: `JSON.parse` and then `for...in`

Answer (score 3):

Iterate the keys and push the values:

```
var stringarray = [];
for (var key in data) {
    stringarray.push(data[key]);
}
```

Comment: hey tymeJV, thanks for your answer, but i tried this before and i'll get this: {,",m,e,s,s,a,g,e,1,",:,",h,a,l,l,o,",,,",m,e,s,s,a,g,e,2,",:,",w,e,l,t,!,",}

Comment: Where does message1 come from?

Answer (score 0):

Use a for-loop to go through the object attributes

```
var obj = {"prop1":"hello","prop2":"world!"};
var array = [];
for(var key in obj){
    array.push(obj[key]);
}
```

Comment: hey izzey, thanks for your answer, but i tried this before and i'll get this: {,",m,e,s,s,a,g,e,1,",:,",h,a,l,l,o,",,,",m,e,s,s,a,g,e,2,",:,",w,e,l,t,!,",}

Comment: How does your original object look?

Answer (score 0):

A "modern" approach worth learning, is, after you've parsed the JSON into a JS object:

```
Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) { return obj[k]; });
```

What's going on here? First, we use `Object.keys` to create an array of all the keys in the object, so `['prop1', 'prop2']`. Then we use the handy `map` function on arrays to transform each of the elements of that array based on a function we give it, which in this case is to retrieve the value for that key from the object.

We could bundle this into a handy little function as follows:

```
function objectValues(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) { return obj[k]; });
}
```

Believe it or not, there is no such thing built into JavaScript, although the Underscore library has `_.values`.

Then you could do something as simple as

```
objectValues(JSON.parse(json))
```